How to stop Apple from sending two factor code to a dead machine?
I've had an Intel based MacBook Pro with a fried GPU which is out of commission but when I log into my Apple ID, Apple seems to send two factor authentication to a great void: It’s nowhere to be found on the Apple devices nearby.
My suspicion is either that dead
in inaction MacBook Pro or an iPad that resides in another location.
Is there a way to stop the codes going out to the fried MacBook Pro?

remove any dead or no longer in use devices from your account as well.

Are you able to sign in to account.apple.com ? It’s not clear how we can help better than apple support since it’s not super clear if you have control of the account.

Where exactly are you trying to log into with your Apple ID?

that was either into developer.apple.com or xcode add account. probably the former to check that pwd works

Apple sends the two-factor code to all authorized devices, so a dead machine that's registered won't interfere with your new devices getting the code.
To inspect which devices can get a code:

Sign in to account.apple.com and view your devices

Or open System Settings / Settings and view your devices


Click the device you want to inspect
Look for a note that says "Can receive Apple Account verification codes"

To remove devices, from the same screen click "Remove from Account"

